# BeautifulSoup going directly into first child's children instead of indexing immediate children

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get to a specific tag in an xml file loaded into a BS object, but when I get to a specific tag, BS is going into the first child when I try an access the children using square brackets '[]'.

for instance, given the xml below, I should get to conditionalBlocks using this python code:

```
reportPages = reportpages.findAll('page')

for reportPage in reportPages:
    contents = reportPage.findAll('pagebody')[0].find_all('contents') #[0].findAll()
    print "contents; ", contents
    conditionalBlocks = contents[0].find_all('conditionalBlocks')
    print "conblox; ", conditionalBlocks
```

Now at `print "contents, "...` I get the output:

```
<contents>
   <textitem>
     <datasource>
        <staticvalue>Foods Management Guide for </staticvalue>
     </datasource>
     <style>
        <defaultStyles>
        <defaultStyle refStyle="wwtxtt"/>
     </style>
   </textitem>
</contents>
```

Which is incomplete as far as I can tell; it only has the contents of the first `textItem` tag within the contents tag and not the other tags that come after

also the line at `print "conblox; ", ...` I get the output;
`conblox;  []`
saying that NO conditionalBlocks tag was found, which; If I look at the xml being read in (see below); is impossible.

I can't understand how it finds the first tag, but not the others, ie: `conditionalBlocks`.
Can someone help explain this please?

here's the XML I'm working with (shortened to make it easy to read):

```
<reportPages>
   <page name="Page1">
    <pageBody>
      <contents>
        <textItem>...</textItem>
        <textItem>...</textItem>
        <block>...</block>
        <block>...</block>
        <conditionalBlocks>
          <conditionalBlockDefault>...</conditionalBlockDefault>
          <conditionalBlockCases refVariable="vView">
            <conditionalBlock refVariableValue="Item Rands">...</conditionalBlock>
            <conditionalBlock refVariableValue="Item Units">...</conditionalBlock>
          </conditionalBlockCases>
        </conditionalBlocks>
     </contents>
     <style>...</style>
   </pageBody>
   <pageHeader>...</pageHeader>
   <pageFooter>...</pageFooter>
   <style>...</style>
   <conditionalRender refVariable="vView">...</conditionalRender>
  </page>
  <page name="Page2">...</page>
</reportPages>
```

Comment: That's because BeautifulSoup attribute access is *not* the same as an XPath. If you use `Tag.some_attribute` the *first* matching child tag is always returned.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is better suited to HTML; use `lxml` (or plain `xml.etree.elementtree` if you want to traverse XML.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so do I use find or findall for that particular tag then?

Comment: but it's a pain using ETree...?

Comment: `.find()` would return the  first match too. You'd have to use `.findall()`. Both ElementTree and `lxml` support XPath searches, with lxml supporting more syntax.

Comment: I would love to use lxml, but my ubuntu machine is at home and I was practically forced to us a mac at work since last month. . . .and a mac is not so friendly with python module installations...I've been through five different, lengthy processes now and I'm yet to install lxml without getting an error

Comment: I use mac all the time, but then again I also use [`buildout.python`](https://github.com/collective/buildout.python) to deal with the small Mac niggles.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is and cite :

> Using a tag name as an attribute will give you only the first tag by that name.

If you want to select all the tags you need to use the `find_all` method because the `find_all` scans the entire document looking for results.

If `find_all` can’t find anything, it returns an empty list.

I recommend you read the BeautifulSoup [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc) for more details.